# merge commands for line-by-line interactive merging with sdiff, in MacOS unix. Is there a working version?

Tags: merge, interactive, sdiff

On MacOS, the sdiff command is described as able to do line-by-line interactive merging, and lists several merge commands for the latest chunk.

e.g. sdiff -o mergefile fileleft fileright

The single letter commands such as l, r (choose left line, choose right line) work well, but those that involve an edit, such as el, ed, er, are troublesome -- they don't work for me. The manual states, e.g.

el: Edit a copy of the left version, then copy the result to the
     output.

When I enter "el" at the % prompt, the response is a number which I think is a character count of the left chunk. There is no temporary file to edit. The command hangs.

Does anyone know of a working version of sdiff ? 
Who should I send a bug report to?

Comment: If you read the manpage, it points to "info diff", which in turn advises you to set `$EDITOR` (otherwise you'll get **`ed`**).

Comment: Thank you. I had read the manpage and "info diff", and I carefully re-read them again, nowhere do I see a mention of setting $EDITOR. subcommand and editing the temporary file, on exit I got message "sdiff: subsidiary program `vi' failed"

Comment: See the end of [9.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Merge-Commands) for `EDITOR`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've had 9.2 printed out in front me and I'd never noticed that!! But as stated in my (mangled) comment above, I set the EDITOR to vi and successfully edited the temp file for an "er" subcommand , but on exit got message "vi failed" and my edits disappeared.

Comment: I'd simply download a current source and compile it (or use MacPorts to get a more recent version).  MacOS's userland is pretty old (typically ten years or more).

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'll spend a couple minutes looking for a source, else abandon the idea. Although I could really use it right now

Comment: It's part of [GNU diffutils](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=diffutils).

Comment: Thank you, yet again!  I'm installing diffutils.

Comment: sdiff now working correctly, thank you for the help